# Displays an image from the database, Picture does not Show using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, phpmyadmin

> > Good evening experts :), i am learning to display images from database using php, i got problem. No error message but image not showing, please help.

this my code headline.php :

```html
<?php
include 'koneksi.php';

$tabel = 'isiberita';
$sql=$conn->query("SELECT * from $tabel order by tanggal desc limit 3");
  while ($tampil = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<p align='justify>'";
    echo "<img src='$tampil[gambar]' aligen='left'>";
    echo "<font valign='top'>";
    echo "<strong>";
    echo $tampil['judul'];
    echo "</strong>";
    echo $tampil['tanggal'];
    $data=substr($tampil['isi'],0,200);
    echo $data;
    echo "<a href='index.php?menu=detail_headline&id=$tampil[id_berita]'>&nbsp; baca lengkap>>>></a>";
    echo "</font></p><br>";
  }

?>
```

This my image directory :
C:\xampp\htdocs\portalberita\gambar

This my headline.php directory :
C:\xampp\htdocs\portalberita

[This my value database :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tAJv.png)

[This output :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C56Xh.png)

Comment: Examine the actual HTML of the output.  What is the `img` element?  Is it what you expect?  When your browser requests that image, what is the server's response?

Answer (score 0):

To show image from a directory in `<img>` tag, you have to specify the image path and name like:

```
<img src="/images/imagename.ext">  <!-- If image folder exist on the same path where the code file exists -->
```

or

```
<img src="../images/imagename.ext">  <!-- If image folder exist one level up where the code file exists -->
```

so check the `image` folder and your code directory and fix the path accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
echo "<img src='$tampil[gambar]' aligen='left'>";
```

with

```
echo '<img src="' . $tampil['gambar'] . '" align="left" />';
```